# How to best setup SQL 2019 with 6 drives?

Tags: database, sql, drive

SQL 2019; Dell R710 2x2.93 GHz x5670; 144 GB RAM; 6 - 2 TB drives

Derived from a previous question (posted here 10 years ago), I figure 3 x RAID 1 is the best way to go. Please correct me if I am wrong or if you think there is a better way. Assume that there are no more available drives to be had...Pulling data mostly from Medical EHR/Practice Management (scheduling) software.

What elements of SQL should go where? From my limited understanding, I think, with the amount of RAM I have, I can install OS on 1st RAID 1 volume and, given that the I/O should be minimal with that much RAM, I could put TempDB/Backup on that volume as well.

Leaving 2nd RAID 1 volume for Data and 3rd RAID 1 volume for Logs.  Thoughts/suggestions?

Just fmi, how much room do Logs and TempDB occupy (as a general rule as compared to the DB)?

Comment: None of your questions can be answered by us. We don't know what your performance or capacity needs are. Separating the SQL program files, the database files, and the log files is considered general best practice, but other than that we can't help you design your storage infrastructure.

Comment: I've seen pretty good answers with a lot less given information... the question is a generalization and should be treated as such. I described the usage case (DB residing on server that is used for Practice Management software) and the existing hardware available. What more do you need to answer the specific questions asked? I did not indicate that speed was an issue and redundancy is a given as per the type of business. Seems that given the parameters are not too vague as to not be able to suggest a best practice given the limitations of those presented. How about being more specific?

Answer (score 0):

With such a low number of mechanical disks, I would create a single RAID10 array partitioned into two different logical disks: a small 100 GB one for the OS, and the other for the database itself.

While separating OS, data and log is a common best practice, it does not apply so clearly to small arrays (you will end with too much partitioning of the already scarse resources).